# Sails.js - can't delete a record and uploaded files

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to delete a record and uploaded files that linked to the records.
But i got an error, and i don't understand how this is happening.

this is a controller.

```
delete: function(req, res){
    console.log(req.param('id'));
    var video = req.param('video');
    Kue_screen.destroy({id:req.param('id')}).exec(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
             res.send('cannot delete');
        }

    fs.unlink("./assets/video"+video, function(err1){
        if(err1){
            console.log(err);
        }
        req.addFlash('success', 'vdieo has been deleted');
        res.redirect('/setting/choose');
        });
    });
    return false;
},
```

this is the error that i got
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out. I forget to announce the primary key. !